# How to make a ListLinePlot from part of data?

Tags: plotting

a) I have tide data for 1 year (365 days). It is easy if I only make a graph for all data using `ListLinePlot`.

The structure of the tide data are: rows = 365, and columns = 24.

For example:

```
{{276, 210, 152, 124, 150, 219, 293, 362, 432, 484, 491, 457, 398, 
  329, 280, 236, 219, 257, 319, 375, 418, 449, 445, 388}, {310, 243, 
  174, 118, 99, 135, 215, 296, 368, 436, 485, 487, 440, 372, 305, 255,
   215, 208, 255, 323, 382, 425, 451, 436}, ... }

Tide = Import["E:\\Tidal data of RIver\\river 2014.csv"]

ListLinePlot[Flatten[Tide]]
```

b) However, I encounter some difficulty to make a graph of tide data using `ListLinePlot` for only 31 days of 365 days. Could anyone hep me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the result of` `l = {3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1};
l[[{1, 3, 5}]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

As noted by belisarius in his comment, you can extract elements of a given list by using the function `Part` whose short-hand is written `[[ ]]`. Other possibilities are `Extract` and `Take`.

---

Here is a proposition that perhaps may be fitted to your specific problem.

We generate the range of dates for the year at stake

```
length = 365;
dates = DateRange["Jan 1st, 2014", DatePlus["Jan 1st, 2014", length - 1]];
```

We gather your data set `tidedata` and the list `dates` into one array

```
datestidedata = Transpose[{dates, tidedata}];
```

We extract a subset of the generated list by means of a "date selector". Here I consider the data for the month of July

```
look[y_, m_, d_] := m == 7;
subdata = Cases[data, {{y_, m_, d_}, tide_} /; look[y, m, d] :> tide];
```

The right-hand side of the function `look` can be defined so that to extract any part of `tidedata` based on the year `y`, the month `m` and the day `d`.

We now use `ListLinePlot` on the resulting expression to plot the hour-by-hour evolution of the tide data each day during the month of July

```
ListLinePlot[subdata]
```